# Beginner: Storing Array Data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

This is a very simple question, but I don't know enough about programming yet to even really know how to ask it.

I'm following a basic, beginners tutorial for creating an iOS app, but modifying it for a personal project.  It has me defining and storing an array of data in a View Controller as such:

```
Station *station001 = [Station new];
station001.name = @"Station 1 Name";
station001.thumbnail = @"station1thumbnail.png";

Station *station002 = [Station new];
station002.name = @"Station 2 Name";
station002.thumbnail = @"station2thumbnail.png";

...

Station *station120 = [Station new];
station120.name = @"Station 120 Name";
station120.thumbnail = @"station120thumbnail.png";

stations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:station001, station002, ... station 120, nil];
```

This is fine, and I understand how to use it in this form.  However, with my app, I have multiple view controllers accessing this same list of data.  Those other view controllers only need certain stations, but need to arrange them in a different order.

I want to assume there is a way to store the first half of the data (creating new 'Station's) so that the View Controllers can all access that same data, and create their array ordering in their respective view controller.  However, I can't seem to find any help for how create such an external file (so I'm assuming it's not the best way to go about this).

All of the tutorials I've seen utilize Property Lists, Core Data, NSUserDefaults and other methods, but these don't seem to explain how to pull just *some* of the data and arrange it in a particular way, depending on the view controller its in.

As a basic next step, I would just like to know a way for multiple view controllers to access my data from a single, external file in XCode.

Any help is appreciated, please forgive how utterly basic and probably obvious the question is!

Comment: Think about how the view controllers know what data they need and how to order them. Then make sure your data array has properties that the view controllers can use to filter data and sort the array. Alternatively, just take a bit more time to learn about Core Data and stick it in there; you'll need to use a real persistence mechanism eventually, anyway; you might as well start now.

Comment: Do you need this data to persist between launches of the app, or not? If not, you shouldn't use Property Lists, Core Data, or NSUserDefaults to store the array. You should probably create a singleton class that creates the array, which each of your controllers can access, then filter and re-order according to their needs.

Comment: @Abizern, no I said that if he doesn't need to persist the data, he shouldn't use any of those methods to share data between controllers.

Comment: My fault, I misread your post. I thought you knew better :)

Comment: I'd suggest as the OP is a beginner, working on a basic, beginners tutorial he might be better off using plists to persist data to start with. Core Data is great, but remember you've been doing this for years.

Comment: Indeed. As a beginner project sticking to plists will be easier. Just saying that there is more…

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I will look into creating a singleton class, as rdelmar suggested, as a start.  Are there perhaps any good resources to use to learn how to go about this?

Comment: If you want to try singleton all you have to do is Google the term and you'll be inundated with examples.  But I'd encourage you to NOT become dependent on the singleton style of programming -- the concept has its use, but it's very easy to let it get away from you, using singletons left and right, and create a nightmare of unintelligible global state.

Comment: If I understand it correctly. I think its fine for you to store all your array values inside a property list then just load the property list in every controller. From there you start filtering and arranging it maybe via index or keys.

Answer (score 0):

For others who came across with this question.

If you need to access the same array list on multiple controllers, you can use property list then just simply load it on every controller where you need it to be.

Your property list xml file could have something like this

```
<dict>
    <array>
     <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>station 1 name</string>
      <key>thumbnail</key>
      <string>stationthumbnail</string>
     </dict>

      <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>station 1 name</string>
      <key>thumbnail</key>
      <string>stationthumbnail</string>
     </dict>

    </array>
 </dict>
```

Loading property list

```
NSString * plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameOfPlistFile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray* pl =[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[pl objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Get dictionary values

```
NSString * name = [dict valueForKey:@"name"]; // returns 'station name 1'
NSString * thumbnail = [dict valueForKey:@"thumbnail"];
```

You can start filtering or do whatever you want with the contents of your plist.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a class that uses the singleton pattern to get you started. In the DataManager class I have one class method to create the shared instance and an instance method to return the array of stations (I also created a Station class that has an initWithName:thumbnail: method to create the stations).

```
@interface DataManager : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *stations;

+(DataManager*)sharedInstance; 



@implementation DataManager

+(DataManager*)sharedInstance {
    static DataManager* sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{ sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(NSArray *)stations {
    if (! _stations) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i=1; i<121; i++) {
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Station %d Name",i];
            NSString *thumb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"station%dthumbnail.png",i];
            Station *aStation = [[Station alloc] initWithName:name thumbnail:thumb];
            [arr  addObject:aStation];
        }
        _stations = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
    }
    return _stations;
}
```

You can then access this array in any other class like this:

```
DataManager *dm = [DataManager sharedInstance];
NSArray *stationArray = dm.stations;
```

Comment: I don't think its necessary to create shared instance for this problem. A simple property list would be simpler and still allows the controller to access the same data every time.